# How to convert time from list of dictionaries to date time format

Tags: python, json, list, dictionary, datetime

I need to convert time from list of dictionaries, that I made from json file, to date time format
the json file looks like this

```
{"name": "Thomas", "time_created": 1665070563, "gender": null}
{"name": "Lisa", "time_created": 1665226717, "gender": "female", "age": 59}
{"name": "James", "time_created": 1664913997, "gender": "male", "last_name": "Rogers"}
{"name": "Helen", "time_created": 1664651357, "gender": "female", "last_name": "Scott"}
{"name": "Nora", "time_created": 1664689732, "gender": "female", "age": null}
```

I try to write this code

```
import jsonlines
import datetime

with jsonlines.open('data.jsonl', 'r') as jsonl_f:
     lst = [obj for obj in jsonl_f]

for value_man in lst:
    for value in value_man.keys():
        value['time_created'] = datetime.datetime.fromtimestamp(value['time_created'])



print(lst)
```

but I have a error here

> value['time_created'] = str(datetime.datetime.fromtimestamp(value['time_created']))
> TypeError: string indices must be integers

Answer (score 0):

You don't need to iterate over all the keys in each dict; the keys are strings, which is why the extra level of iteration is giving you a string instead of the actual dict.  Just do:

```
for value in lst:
    value['time_created'] = datetime.datetime.fromtimestamp(value['time_created'])
```

You can also do this:

```
lst = [obj for obj in jsonl_f]
```

more simply as:

```
lst = list(jsonl_f)
```

Answer (score 0):

You are accessing the key of the dictionary, not the value. You have to actually access the value, something along those lines:

```
import jsonlines
import datetime

with jsonlines.open('data.jsonl', 'r') as jsonl_f:
     lst = [obj for obj in jsonl_f]

for value_man in lst:
    for value in value_man.keys():
        if value == 'time_created':
            value_man[value] = datetime.datetime.fromtimestamp(value_man[value])
```

print(lst)